# Moved Xcode folder to new computer, now TONS of files are missing

Tags: xcode, xcode5, file-management

You can only imagine how frustrated I am, trying to go through my old computer finding where all the resources are and putting them on the new one.

Please tell me how I can, next time, prevent this from happening. When I copy files into Xcode, I actually want to *copy* them in there. Not just use the file location.

Comment: Compress them and transfer. You will get all files...

Comment: Thanks immi, compress as in... Archive it into the organizer, or put the folder in a zip?

Comment: Just to clarify... did you move Xcode.app, the IDE, or an Xcode project folder?

Answer (score 0):

When adding files to a project you'll get asked if Xcodeshould copy them. If you allow that, they are copied. otherwise consider using a version control system, that allows you to clone your project on another computer.